# Python 3.x - How to ask the user to input whether two sides of two triangles are parallel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
shape= 'Triangle'
name_1='ABC'
name_2='DEF'
Yes= 'Yes'
No= 'No'

if shape == 'Triangle':
    parallel= input("Is there two parallel sides in", shape+"s", name_1," and", name_2,"? Please Enter Yes or No: ")
    while parallel != Yes and parallel != No:
        print("Please Enter Yes or No.")
        parallel= input("Is there two parallel sides in", shape+"s", name_1," and", name_2,"? Please Enter Yes or No: ")
    if parallel == Yes:
        ParallelSides_1= input("Please Enter the 1st parallel side. E.G. AB. Input: ")
        while ParallelSides_1 not in name_1 and ParallelSides_1 not in name_2:
            print("This side does not belong to", shape+"s", name_1,"and", name_2)
        ParallelSides_2= input("Please Enter the 2nd parallel side. E.G. EF. Input: ")
        if ParallelSides_1 in name_1:
            while ParallelSides_2 not in name_2:
                print("This side does not belong to", shape, name_2)
                ParallelSides_2= input("Please Enter the 2nd parallel side. E.G. EF. Input: ")
        if ParallelSides_1 in name_2:
            while ParallelSides_2 not in name_1:
                print("This side does not belong to", shape, name_1)
                ParallelSides_2= input("Please Enter the 2nd parallel side. E.G. EF. Input: ")

    print(ParallelSides_1,"and", ParallelSides_2,"are parallel.")
```

My problem is that when ever I run this code I get a lot of errors. I do not know how to fix them. One of the errors is:

> line 8, in 
>       parallel= input("Is there two parallel sides in", shape+"s", name_1," and", name_2,"? Please Enter Yes or No: ") TypeError: input
>   expected at most 1 arguments, got 6

What I want this code to do is to see whether there are parallel lines in both triangles and check if they belong to the 1st triangle (name_1) and the 2nd triangle.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what the errors are? `Yes` and `No` are not variables. That'd be the first error...

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that but I still get this error:line 8, in <module>
    parallel= input("Is there two parallel sides in", shape+"s", name_1," and", name_2,"? Please Enter Yes or No: ")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 6

Comment: You don't use commas to combine strings... Input function only takes one string

Comment: How do you combine more that one string. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You *go read a tutorial*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "," with "+" in line 8 and 11:

```
parallel= input("Is there two parallel sides in " + shape + "s" + name_1 + " and " +  name_2 + "? Please Enter Yes or No: ")
```